# How to send multiple Javascript variables to PHP using jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My question seeks an answer more like "how to proceed"..

I have a document where after muliple user interactions, I end up with three javascript variables. 1 integer and 2 strings arrays, they may be like this..

```
integer: 66
array1: ["100.01", "200.05", "100.15"]
array2: ["2", "23", "24"]
```

I need to send those variable via POST to a PHP file using jQuery AJAX. The PHP file should then process those variables as they are, an integer, and arrays.

So basically, my question is, how do I send this 3 different types of variables in the same AJAX call? and... on the server side how do I receive them? 
`(json_decode($_POST['myVariable']))` ??

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Q: what should send what from where to where? Is that above php in the script handling the ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer you can just send as a regular parameter (I imagine you'd probably need to convert from a string to an integer server-side). For the arrays I'd suggest converting to JSON strings (using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)), like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        integer: integer,
        array1: JSON.stringify(array1),
        array2: JSON.stringify(array2)
    },
    ...
});
```

Then in your PHP you'd use something like `json_decode($_POST['array1'])` to get back the array1 POST parameter as an actual array.

Disclaimer: I don't code in PHP, I've just picked up bits and pieces from reading questions and answers on StackOverflow. I can't guarantee the server-side parts will work precisely, but they should be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like data in the call below? Of course with your data then ;)

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "../WebService",
     type: 'POST',
     data: { recipient: mailrecipient, input: content },
     dataType: 'xml',
     success: function (xmldata, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

         alert("Mail sent to:\n" + mailrecipient);
        }
});
```

Comment: that would be clientside, Q is what OP means with the `json_decode(...` stuff which is obviously serverside

Comment: @AxelAmthor If you want to be picky then he is actually asking two questions whereof I am answering one :)

Comment: not being picky, but this is a kind of "I-should-have-read-that-book-entirely" case ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a REST-like approach like:

```
http://your-server?int=integervalue&str1=string2value&str2=string2value
```

On your Server you could then read all those URL-Params...sorry i don't know how to do it in php.
But in jQuery-ajax it would look like

jQuery.ajax({url:url, params:{'int1':integervalue,'string1':string1value, 'string2': strin2value});

Answer (score 0):

Post data like this

```
var sData = JSON.stringify({integers: 66,array1: ["100.01", "200.05", "100.15"],array2: ["2", "23", "24"]});

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"getData.php",
    data:sData,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);  
    },
    error: function(){}
});
```

in `getData.php` access these data like this

```
$results = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$int = $results->integers;
$arr1 = $results->array1;
$arr2 = $results->array2;
$value1 = 0;

foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
    $value1 += $value;
}

echo json_encode($value1); // you will get response as 49(2 + 23  +24)
```